# Create a disk image of a dualboot system with dd

Tags: disk-image

I would like to create a disk image of a dual boot system (Ubuntu, Windows 11).
Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda1` and Windows 11 on `/dev/sdb1`

How can I accomplish the task with the `dd` command?
I tried `sudo dd if=/dev/sda if=/dev/sdb of=dualboot.img bs=64K conv=noerror,sync`. However after two seconds the clone option stops leaving behind a image size of 4096 bytes.

Comment: dd does not support multiple `if=`. You shouldn't use noerror,sync either. Since you have two separate drives, why not backup them separately?

Comment: You should not use dd as a backup tool. It also copies empty space, so both takes a lot longer & makes larger files. Use Windows tools for Windows. I prefer not to back up Ubuntu system (root), but use rsync to backup /home, some settings in / and list of installed apps to make it easy to restore. And I do that to multiple drives at different times. discussion of alternatives/strategy backups
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465713 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: I would use [Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248) for that task.